# Error installing pgspecial, it keeps trying to call/use psycopg2, instead of the psycopg2-binary already installed

Tags: python, docker, pip, jupyter, psycopg2

I'm running Jupyter Notebook with Docker on Windows 10. I already installed psycopg2-binary. I used the command "pip install pgspecial" but got the error "Collecting psycopg2>=2.7.4 (from pgspecial)". It looks like it keeps trying to install psycopg2 (which doesn't work on my pc), ignoring the psycopg2-binary already installed.

[jupyter terminal screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx8mX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is something you will need to take up with the pgspecial maintainers. Their setup.py has:

```
 install_requires=[
        'click >= 4.1',
        'sqlparse >= 0.1.19',
        'psycopg2 >= 2.7.4',
    ],
```

psycopg2 is different from psycopg2-binary.